# Can I label the x-axis as \rho, the Greek letter in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, markdown

I have used \alpha, \lambda e.t.c to label axes in matplotlib, but it seems that \rho is not allowed. Is it because not every Greek letter is allowed? Can I label the x-axis as \rho?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from np.random import normal

plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.linspace(0,10,100), normal(0,1,100), color="darkblue")
plt.xlabel("$\rho$")
plt.ylabel("Values")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it and you must have been really close if you got alpha and lambda to display.

What you missed is the r in front of it. It should look like this:

`plt.xlabel(r"$\rho$")`

[Here is the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/text/mathtext.html?highlight=rho)